# Creating fly through video of 3D map in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, animation

I'm currently working on creating a 3D map in ArcScene of a watershed proximal to my college campus. I've had trouble saving the work but am capable of creating the map relatively quickly now, just not able to save it. My ultimate goal is to create a video of the map as it is flown through.

Does anyone know of a reputable program to download that can create a video of what ever is on the computer screen?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to export your fly-through to video from ArcScene, without any need for external software.  Look for the export option in the [animation toolbar](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00090000004s000000.htm) drop-down menu.  Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.gistutor.com/esri-arcgis/1-beginner-arcgis-tutorials/61-how-to-record-a-3d-flyover-animation-using-esris-arcscene.html) for instance.

Alternatively, I sometimes use [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) for screen capture.  It is free and easy to use.  However, in general, rendering to a video from within a program is usually better than screen capture as you usually have more control over resolution etc.

Comment: Great, thank you for the info on the animation toolbar drop down menu. I'll be sure to have a look at the touturial as well.